# @synchronized parameter with same value but different reference?

Tags: ios, objective-c, synchronization

I have a question about the parameter that `@synchronized` take, I have read the Apple document about synchronisation but still I don't have a clear idea.

I have a case that `@synchronized` will take a string property inside some object like this :

```
@synchronized(someObject.A)
```

since A is a `NSString` object and in some cases will carry the same value but from different `someObject` is this will guarantee the locking for all objects with same A values?

Comment: I don't know O-C but I think it means it's synchronization on the reference itself, not necessarily the value at that reference.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that `NSString` has some special cases that are handled magically.

```
NSString *s1 = @"Test string";
NSString *s2 = @"Test string";
```

Here, `s1` and `s2` are actually compiled to access the same memory address, even though they are different variables and could be instantiated in completely different places within the application.

However, if you are loading the data on-the-fly or using one of the construction methods for `NSString` instead of hard-coding it, strings that match character-for-character will not share the same memory.

You can consider this the difference between comparing with `==` and `isEqualToString:`. `@synchronized` only ever uses the `==` result.

So, to answer your question: *maybe*.

If you are using hard-coded values of the form `@"some string"` within your application, your `@synchronized` command will link to all objects that share the same textual value for `A`.

If you are creating `NSString` objects by any other means, your `@synchronized` command will only link to objects that point to the exact same `NSString` object.

Answer (score 0):

The synchronization will be done on whatever object `someObject.A` is currently referencing. The important piece is the actual object you use `@synchronized` on.

If you assign the same string to two completely difference properties and you then use `@synchronized` on those two completely different properties, it will work since both point to the same string.

The following example may help:

```
// In one method
@synchronized(someObject.A) {
}

// In another method
NSString *foo = someObject.A;
@synchronized(foo) {
}
```

The above two blocks will be thread safe on the same string object.